# How to calculate the variation of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

Suppose we have two diagonal matrices

$$
A_{\mu \nu}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\rho(t) & 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0
\end{array}\right)
$$

and 
$$
B_{\mu\nu}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0& 0& 0\\
0& a(t)& 0& 0\\
0& 0& b(t)& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0
\end{array}\right)
$$

Now if we vary $B_{\mu\nu}$ by a small amount i.e. $B_{\mu\nu}\rightarrow B_{\mu\nu}+\delta{B_{\mu\nu}}$. Does $A$ vary under this variation? I mean what is $\delta{A_{\mu\nu}}$?

Comment: $\rho(t)$ is not in $B_{\mu\nu}$...

Comment: @Jonas, but what if $\rho(t)$ depends on $a(t)$ or $b(t)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $$A_{\mu \nu}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\rho(a(t),b(t)) & 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0
\end{array}\right)$$ and

$$B_{\mu\nu}+\delta B_{\mu\nu}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0& 0& 0\\
0& a(t)+\epsilon h(t)& 0& 0\\
0& 0& b(t)+\epsilon k(t)& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0
\end{array}\right)$$ then

$$A_{\mu \nu}+\delta A_{\mu \nu}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\rho(a(t)+\epsilon h(t),b(t)+\epsilon k(t)) & 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0
\end{array}\right),$$ from where

$$\delta A_{\mu \nu}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\rho(a(t)+\epsilon h(t),b(t)+\epsilon k(t))-\rho(a(t),b(t)) & 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0
\end{array}\right).$$ Now, an explicit expression depends on $\rho.$ For example, if $\rho(a(t),b(t))=a(t)+b(t)$ then
$$\delta A_{\mu \nu}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\epsilon (h(t)+k(t)) & 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0
\end{array}\right)$$ and if $\rho(a(t),b(t))=a(t)\cdot b(t)$ then
$$\delta A_{\mu \nu}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\epsilon (a(t)k(t)+b(t)h(t))+\epsilon^2 h(t)k(t) & 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0
\end{array}\right).$$

Comment: If $\rho(t)$ didn't depend on $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ would $A$ change if we vary $B$?

Comment: Well, if we don't know of any relation between $A$ and $B,$ the answer is no. $\rho(t)$ only depends on $t.$ So, it is not affected by any change in $B.$

Comment: A variation of $a(t)$ is $a(t)+\epsilon h(t).$ This doesn't change $t.$ Note that we are introducing a new parameter $\epsilon.$

Comment: Suppose $\rho(t)$ doesn't depend on $a(t)$ then if we vary $a(t)$ then we must have $\frac{\partial{\rho}}{\partial{a}}=0$, but $\frac{\partial{\rho}}{\partial{a}}=\frac{\partial{\rho}}{\partial{t}}\frac{ \partial t}{\partial{a}}\neq {0}$ since $\frac{\partial{\rho}}{\partial{t}}\neq {0}$ and $\frac{\partial{a}}{\partial{t}}\neq {0}$. Isn't this a contradiction?

Comment: It's not a contradiction. Note that the variation depends on the parameter $\epsilon.$ And since $\frac{\partial a}{\partial \epsilon}=0$ you have $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial \epsilon}=\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial \epsilon}=0.$ That is, $\rho$ is not affected by the variation.

Comment: Isn't $\frac{\partial{a}}{\partial \epsilon}=\frac{\partial{(a+\epsilon h)}}{\partial \epsilon}=h(t)$?

Comment: No. $a$ is independent of $\epsilon.$ Of course $\delta a$ depends on $\epsilon$ but not $a.$